# Is there a web application, which can provide me a slow loading page for testing?

Tags: testing, html

Better still, may be it can provide load time parameterized web page. I know, I am asking for too much.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about the real value of a slow loading page, but here we go:

Download [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and install it

Save the following code to `slowpage.rb`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/sleep/:seconds' do
    sleep(params[:seconds].to_f)
    "Yay, I just waited #{params[:seconds]} seconds"
end
```

At the command line type:

```
gem install sinatra
ruby slowpage.rb
```

Then open your browser and go to http://localhost:4567/sleep/5, which will take about 5 seconds to load the page.

Comment: Like this. Want something which is public. Don't tell me to host this on heroku :) . May be I should do just that.

Comment: Heroku would be a good choice. You'll get clustering and fail-over ;).  Out of curiosity: What do you need it for?

Comment: Was testing iframe loading with a masked back ground image, and it looks darn hard to find a slow page. For ref: http://jsfiddle.net/Xrmg9/14/